# Calculating % of days VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, sql-server-2012, percentage

How is it possible to calculate the percentage of days completed by using VB.NET?

The datareader takes `project_start` and `project_finished`, stored as `Date()` in SQL-Server-2012.

This is what I tried:

```
Dim StartDate As New Date(datareader("project_start"))
Dim FinishDate As New Date(datareader("project_finish"))
Dim Percentage As Date = Date.FromOADate(StartDate.DayOfYear) / Date.FromOADate(FinishDate.DayOfYear) / 100
```

But I get this error:

```
Operator '/' is not defined for types 'Date' and 'Date'.
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "percentage of days completed"?

Comment: Think a bit about what you are doing - trying to divide _dates_. What does that even mean?

Comment: Take a look into [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) - this should help you to get the desired result. Subtracting Startdate from EndDate will give you a TimeSpan representing 100%.

Comment: Also what does `DayOfYear` do for you exactly? What if a project started on Dec 18th and finished on Jan 12th? Also doesn't another piece of information need to be known (e.g. is that the actual project finish date, or are you trying to compare the finish date to *today's* date)? Have you looked at [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) in SQL Server? It can calculate this without all this type messiness and conversion in your front end.

Answer (score 4):

You need to substract Dates and use TotalDays property. The example code below:

```
Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-50)
Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(50)

Dim today As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Dim sumDays = (endDate - start).TotalDays
Dim daysToNow = (today - start).TotalDays

Dim percentage = daysToNow / sumDays * 100

Console.WriteLine(percentage)

Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Won't this perform an integer division? (It would in C#) I would write `Dim percentage = CDbl(daysToNow) / sumDays * 100`

Comment: TotalDays is double, I tested this code in C# and then converted it ti vb.net:-)